# Changing image using Select option drop down, but for multiple events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, select

Using JQuery to change an image on the change of a select, the code works, on one form, however if I try to apply to same thing to another form the JQuery just doesn't work. Need to implement this one a basis where I can use the same code to change individual select.

Feel free to run the code and see what I mean, the first item works, change the select option to red, the image changes, try the same with the next one, no luck although its written in the same fashion.

If you need anything else let me know, thanks in advance.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#colour").on('change', function(){
    $("#imageToSwap").attr("src", $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-src"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <ul class="shelf">
  <li class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
      <img id="imageToSwap" class="item_thumb" src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagBlack.png" />
      <h4 class="item_name">C&amp;J Wash Bag</h4>
      <span class="item_price">£30.00</span>
    <select id="colour">
    <option value="Black" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagBlack.png">Black</option>
    <option value="Red" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagRed.png">Red</option>
</select>
      <select class="item_quantity">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option> 
   </select>
      <input type="hidden" class="item_shipping" value="0" />
      <input type="button" class="item_add" value="Add To Basket" />
  </li>

  <li class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
      <img id="imageToSwap" class="item_thumb" src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBrown.png" />
      <h4 class="item_name">C&amp;J Wool Lined Gloves</h4>
      <span class="item_price">£28.00</span>
       <select id="colour">
    <option value="Brown" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBrown.png">Brown</option>
    <option value="Tan" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesTan.png">Tan</option>
    <option value="Black" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBlack.png">Black</option>
    <option value="Grey" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesGrey.png">Grey</option>
</select>
      <select required class="item_quantity">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option> 
   </select>
      <input type="hidden" class="item_shipping" value="0" />
      <input type="button" class="item_add" value="Add To Basket" />
  </li></ul>
```

Comment: Does your other `form` exists in the same page?

Comment: Make sure there are no duplicate IDs in your page...

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, didn't mean to refer to multiple forms, I meant multiple select boxes, I have updated the post appropriately .

Comment: Change `id="colour"` to `class="colour"` in html for you select elements and `$("#colour")` to `$(".colour")` in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad thing to give same id to multiple element. There is same ID used for multiple element. Make it unique it works.

You can use class instead of id. like Here i give `colour` class and change image using sibling selector.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".colour").on('change', function(){
       $(this).siblings(".item_thumb").attr("src", $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-src"));
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <ul class="shelf">
  <li class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
      <img id="imageToSwap" class="item_thumb" src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagBlack.png" />
      <h4 class="item_name">C&amp;J Wash Bag</h4>
      <span class="item_price">£30.00</span>
    <select id="colour" class="colour">
    <option value="Black" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagBlack.png">Black</option>
    <option value="Red" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagRed.png">Red</option>
</select>
      <select class="item_quantity">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option> 
   </select>
      <input type="hidden" class="item_shipping" value="0" />
      <input type="button" class="item_add" value="Add To Basket" />
  </li>

  <li class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
      <img id="imageToSwap1" class="item_thumb" src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBrown.png" />
      <h4 class="item_name">C&amp;J Wool Lined Gloves</h4>
      <span class="item_price">£28.00</span>
       <select id="colour1" class="colour">
    <option value="Brown" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBrown.png">Brown</option>
    <option value="Tan" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesTan.png">Tan</option>
    <option value="Black" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBlack.png">Black</option>
    <option value="Grey" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesGrey.png">Grey</option>
</select>
      <select required class="item_quantity">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option> 
   </select>
      <input type="hidden" class="item_shipping" value="0" />
      <input type="button" class="item_add" value="Add To Basket" />
  </li></ul>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with the same ID? I'm having to put up to 20 of the same type of select boxes on one page all requiring the same function and want to avoid numbering up the JQuery, thanks for your answer though, if all else fails!

Comment: Just use class instead of id.

Comment: You can not use same id for multiple. Use class instead then.

Comment: This works! Thanks! However doesn't change the individual picture above the correct selector, instead it always changes the first options image, if that makes sense? (with the id="imageToSwap")

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you have "imageToSwap" duplicated.  Therefore the function isn't able to locate the correct object to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

As part of W3C rules, a **`html cannot contain duplicate ids`**. So I would suggest to change the `ids` and perform your color change by picking up `class` as below:

**Changes -**

- Added class `colorChange` to your color `select` element and changed its 
  `id`s
- Changed `event change` to fire on `class` and getting the actual target image with `$(this)` reaching to its `parent li` and getting the `img` with class `image_thumb`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".colorChange").on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.item_thumb').attr("src", $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-src"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="shelf">
  <li class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <img id="imageToSwap" class="item_thumb" src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagBlack.png" />
    <h4 class="item_name">C&amp;J Wash Bag</h4>
    <span class="item_price">£30.00</span>
    <select id="colour" class="colorChange">
      <option value="Black" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagBlack.png">Black</option>
      <option value="Red" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/washbagRed.png">Red</option>
    </select>
    <select class="item_quantity">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" class="item_shipping" value="0" />
    <input type="button" class="item_add" value="Add To Basket" />
  </li>

  <li class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <img id="imageToSwap1" class="item_thumb" src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBrown.png" />
    <h4 class="item_name">C&amp;J Wool Lined Gloves</h4>
    <span class="item_price">£28.00</span>
    <select id="colour1" class="colorChange">
      <option value="Brown" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBrown.png">Brown</option>
      <option value="Tan" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesTan.png">Tan</option>
      <option value="Black" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesBlack.png">Black</option>
      <option value="Grey" data-src="http://candj.azurewebsites.net/PHP/2/shelf_img/glovesGrey.png">Grey</option>
    </select>
    <select required class="item_quantity">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" class="item_shipping" value="0" />
    <input type="button" class="item_add" value="Add To Basket" />
  </li>
</ul>
```